# Is there a way to add more text to a range value?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, morph-x

I'm trying to extend a query in Dynamics AX that populates the "My Projects" window. I've found the query that I need to modify, and tried to modify it, unfortunately, the character limit in the Value field (see screen shot), is not sufficient to allow me to enter all of the text I need to extend this query.

[image]

I've explored adding additional ranges, but I need to add additional OR arguments here and it appears that adding additional ranges will AND the range instead of ORing it.

Is there any way to bypass this character limit?

Comment: Can you please provide a bigger screenshot - yours is too small so it isn't possible to see the objects you are trying to show.
In some cases you can avoid such issues by creating and using new Views.

Answer (score 0):

If you add several ranges to the same datasource field, the ranges are combined with `OR` in the SQL.

This is useful sometimes. See [this queustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797517/dynamics-ax-2009-x-selecting-a-date-range) for a (klunky) example.